# GCC error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I'm getting `error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode` when I try to compile with `make`. I found a [wiki](http://cplusplus.syntaxerrors.info/index.php?title=%27for%27_loop_initial_declaration_used_outside_C99_mode) that says

> Put -std=c99 in the compilation line: `gcc -std=c99 foo.c -o foo`

Problem is I don't know how to specify this in `make`. I opened *Makefile*, found `CC = gcc` and changed it to `CC = gcc -std=c99` with no results. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe add `-std=c99` to the `CFLAGS` variable?

Comment: You could also fix that `for` loop!

Comment: Did you run again `make` after having edited your `Makefile` ?

Comment: I added the `-stc=c99` to `CFLAGS` in `Makefile` and ran `make` but got the same error. Fixing the `for` loop worked.

Comment: It's -std=c99 not -stC=c99. You also have the option to change the loop to: int i; for (i=0;...;...)

Comment: oops, typo here. yes I changed the loop as you said

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put CFLAGS=-std=c99 at the top of your Makefile.

To remove the error without using C99, you just need to declare your iterator variable at the top of the block the for loop is inside.

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{

}
```

Use:

```
int i;
//other code
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks! CFLAGS didn't work but I changed the for loops and that fixed it.

Comment: CFLAGS should have worked. Double check you makefile file and run make again. May be you can also try to compile the file without using make, just to test.

Comment: @JohnTortugo: ended up in the same situation - `CFLAGS=-std=c99` did not change behaviour, but fixing the loop... Compiling nettle-3.4.1, offending loop in `rsa-sign-tr.c:243`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

NEW: i tried `make CFLAGS=-std=c99`,finally useful.

OLD:if you have added `CFLAGS=-std=c99` into MakeFile,and got error too.

maybe use `make clean` before `make` is a good idea.

Comment: it's crazy, i tried `make CFLAGS=-std=c99`,finally useful.