# 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode

Tags: c, dev-c++

Any ideas why I am getting that error? I thought I'd done everything fine, it wasn't showing any errors before I coded past it?

```
for (int i=0;i<height;i++)
{
    if (i == 0 || i == height-1 )
    {
        for (int j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            printf("%i_",paddings);
            if (j == width-1)
            {
                printf("%i\n",paddings);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC error: 'for' loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690142/gcc-error-for-loop-initial-declaration-used-outside-c99-mode)

Comment: which error, wt you mean by "that error" ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hold-back from the days of ANSI C. Basically, it means that you must declare variables for use in `for` loops like so:

```
// Looping variables declared outside the loops
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 || i == height - 1)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            printf("%i_", paddings);
            if (j == width - 1)
            {
                printf("%i\n", paddings);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could change your compiler flags so that it uses C99 or above. For `gcc` this would simply entail adding the compile flag `-std=c99`, or for C11, `-std=c11`

Comment: for (int j=0;j<width;j++)

This is now showing an error :/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; ...)
```

is a C99 extension; in order to use it you must enable it via specific compiler flags in gcc

For old standards like C89 is:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; ...)
```

You must declare your variables outside the loop.